# Create loosely typed udf similar to ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to create a udf where the return type is the same as the first argument.

Other notes:

- The first argument can be any type and if it is null the return value is null with no underlying type.
- Constraints on the second argument so the type matches that of the first.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210(v=SQL.80).aspx

Comment: There is no *type* of NULL. A datatype can have a NULL "value".

Comment: Are you trying to replicate ISNULL, or just trying to make your own user UDF with the same signature + behaviour as ISNULL with more user code within?

Comment: That would be a possibility. I am doing a refactoring of a client database and there are ISNULL(NULLIF(A.Whatever, ''), 'NA') statements everywhere. I thought of wrapping the above statement but couldn't get it to work like I wanted. This is more of a inquiry than anything. I hadn't thought of how ISNULL worked until I tried to wrap it for my own use.

Comment: Not sure of the purpose. You're going to create a user-defined function so that you can replace ISNULL(NULLIF( with dbo.myfunction(? What have you gained? Maybe better to examine whether allowing these NULLs all over the place is the best thing in every case.

Comment: Well the project is migrating the old schema to a new one. The current one isn't normalized at all with duplicate data in multiple tables. So wrapping the ISNULL/NULLIF functionality would improve encapsulation in my migration queries. Either way, the purpose of the question was to figure out if it was possible to duplicate the type inference functionality of the ISNULL function... or just about any aggregate function for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [sql_variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) datatype for a UDF. (I've haven't BTW)

However, a simple in-line ISNULL use the datatype of the 1st argument anyway.

Unless you haven't given us full information in the question about what you intend to achieve...

Edit: after update

The whole point of ISNULL is to replace a NULL (1st argument) with a value (2nd argument).

There is no "type" of NULL. An int or a varchar can take a NULL value. But it's still the base datatype

ISNULL constrains 2nd argument to the 1st type anyway: the 2nd argument must be implicitly convertible. So `SELECT ISNULL(CAST(NULL AS int), 'foo')` will fail

So, use in-line ISNULL which does what you want. A udf is not needed

Edit, after comment

You can't have one udf to cover all datatypes.

Not least, a udf has a single return datatype.

Comment: I tried using sql_variant. The problem is there are a lot of types it cant store and the ones it can must be cast before it can be used correctly. Instances where isnull can be used without any issues.

Comment: @Joshua Dale: I haven't use sql_variant with a UDF as I said. I'd use in-line ISNULL and not try to be clever.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how ISNULL operates. It doesn't have to be ISNULL, there are plenty of other functions that work the same way. Nothing wrong with being clever.

Comment: @Joshua Dale: then ask "how ISNULL operates". There are no other functions that act as ISNULL: it's non-standard

Comment: @gbn: `NULLIF` seems to behave in a very similar way to `ISNULL`.

Comment: a udf can return a sql_variant too.

Comment: @Andriy M: It is similar, but oposite of isnull. Isnull checks for a null value and outputs a default where isnull checks for a condition and outputs null if true. In my example I wrapped both to check for a null or empty string.

Comment: @G Mastros: It can, but unfortunately there are too many types sql_variant can't contain. Also I would need to cast/convert every time I would need to use it.

Comment: @Joshua Dale: Yes, that's pretty much what I've gathered too. I was pointing out to @gbn that ISNULL is probably not entirely unique in how it operates and that NULLIF acts similarly, meaning that the latter, too, can both receive and return different data types.

Comment: Ah, gotya. Thanks for your participation with my question.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server's `ISNULL()`, as you point out, takes 2 params, the first being an expression of any type, and the second being the replacement if the first arg is null. It returns the same type as the arg being checked.

> check_expression : Is the expression to be checked for NULL. **check_expression can be of any type**.
>
> replacement_value : expression to be returned if check_expression is NULL. replacement_value **must have the same type as check_expression**.
>
> Return Types: Returns the **same type** as check_expression.

It sounds from your edited question as if ISNULL already does what you're after.

Comment: Exactly. I need the return type to be the same as the first argument. I'll try to edit my question to clear that up.